# Angular 4 slide using scrolling event

Tags: angular, animation

I can't seems to get it right. I manage to setup nicely using the `@HostListener` to get the `window:scroll` working but I am not certain how to attach the className which animates the div to slide up using CSS animations to trigger the animation when scrolling.

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', [])
onWindowScroll() {
  const number = this.document.body.scrollTop;
  if(number > 150 || number > 150) {
    this.isScrolled = document.getElementsByClassName('work-row').className = 'slideUp';
  }
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: This helps you enough https://angular.io/api/animations/trigger ?

Answer (score 0):

Use **addEventListener** and **renderer2** this way

===================================================

Best way to add a class is using renderer2.According to your Question it seems like you want to add a class dynamically after certain scroll level?
So use the Renderer 2 to add a class like this

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2, AnimationStyles, AnimationKeyframe, AnimationPlayer } from '@angular/core';
```

once you imported inject that into the constructer like this

```
    constructor(
    public element: ElementRef, 
    public renderer: Renderer2, 
 ){}
```

Now use this way to add your class dynamically

```
this.renderer.addClass(this.ele_img,'slidup')
```

here `this.ele_img` is the element which you want to animate 
This way it works

```
 import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    export class HomePage {
                 constructor( 
                        public element: ElementRef, 
                        public renderer: Renderer2, 
                        ){}
                        ngOnInit() {
                               this.header = this.element.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName('scroll-content')[0];
                               const number = this.header.scrollTop;
                               this.ele_img = this.element.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName('img')[0];}
                               this.header.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
                                     if(number > 150 || number > 150) {
                                     this.renderer.addClass(this.ele_img,'slidup')
                                    }

                               });
                        }

  }
```